# Infer subclass property type from base class generic in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
class A<T>
{
    some: { [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K]) => T[K] }
}

interface IB {
    b: number
}

class B<T extends IB> extends A<T>
{
    constructor()
    {
        super()

        /**
         * Type '{ b: (x: T["b"]) => number; }'
         * is not assignable to type '{ [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K]) => T[K]; }'.
         */
        this.some = {
            b: x => 2*x
        }
    }
}

interface IC {
    b: number
    c: boolean
}

class C<T extends IC> extends B<T>
{
    constructor()
    {
        super()
        /**
         * Type '{ b: (x: T["b"]) => number; c: (x: T["c"]) => boolean; }'
         * is not assignable to type '{ [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K]) => T[K]; }'
         */
        this.some = {
            b: x => 4*x,
            c: x => !x
        }
    }
}
```

Hello. I try to set generic constraint in base class "A" with the aim to automatically infer types of "some" properties in derived classes. Unfortunately I can't understand why I get TS errors like I have mentioned above. Everything seems ok from my point of view.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What should happen if I do this?

```
const b = new B<{ b: 3, z: string }>();
```

As you can see, I've passed in the type `{ b: 3, z: string }`, which is acceptable because it extends `{ b: number }`.  So that means `b.some.b` should be of type `(x: 3) => 3`.  And it also means `b.some.z` should be of type `(x: string) => string`.  Are either of those true of the implementation of `B`? No; `b.some.b` is actually of type `(x: 3) => number`, and `b.some.z` is undefined.  So it makes sense that the compiler is warning you.

First, let's take care of the `z: string` issue.  Perhaps in `A` you want the properties of `some` to be optional, like this:

```
class A<T>
{
  some: {[K in keyof T]?: (x: T[K]) => T[K]}
}
```

This would allow your `B` and `C` constructor to initialize `some` without having to know about extra properties.

Now, about `b: 3`.  If you want to allow for someone to extend `number`, then the only safe thing you can use is the identity function:

```
this.some = {};
this.some.b = x => x; // okay
```

But probably you don't want anyone to pass in anything more specific than `number` for the type of `b`.  Unfortunately there's no great way to prevent it.  So, fine, just document that users should only pass in types where `b` can be any `number`.  In this case you need to just tell the compiler not to worry, by asserting that `this` is of type `B<IB>`:

```
this.some = {};
(this as B<IB>).some.b = x => 2 * x; // okay
```

Similar fixes can be done for your `C` class.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: This is a very detailed answer :) Now everything is clear with your help. Thank you so much!